# spliting Hex data using Python

Tags: python, parsing, numbers

I have sets of this data : 0018f3aaaaa955554e0000 (00 18 f3 ... each being a byte)

I am trying to get 4th,5th,6th and 7th,8th,9th octets by seperating into

00 18 f3 **aa aa a9** **55 55 4e** 00 00 then get aaaaa9, 55554e.

What would be best way to achieve this using python?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the FAQ and How to Ask.

Comment: What your conveying to me by your question is that you don't know how to start this project/assignment, and your asking how to start. I'm sorry, but this comes across to me as asking for "skeleton" or "starter" code. Either way, both are asking for code to be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `decode('hex')` and `encode('hex')` string methods to accomplish this:

```
>>> hex_bytes = '0018f3aaaaa955554e0000'
>>> data = hex_bytes.decode('hex')
>>> data[3:6].encode('hex')
'aaaaa9'
>>> data[6:9].encode('hex')
'55554e'
```

Comment: Random notice: this won’t work on Python 3, where you’ll need `codecs.decode` :)